# SQL Server 2008 : ALTER IDENTITY TYPE

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

I have an existing table `MCheckTypes` and it has a primary key column `ID`. What I want to do is to alter the table to add identity type on the primary key. I don't want to drop a table and recreate a new one. I already google it but no luck. Below is my script

```
ALTER TABLE MCheckTypes 
   ALTER COLUMN [ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
```

below is the error message

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IDENTITY'.

Comment: Is your existing ID column is just primary key without identity?

Comment: yes, absolutely, ID column is existing and it's a primary key

Comment: to Raj, i already see that link when i google it. but answers doesn't work. That image is exactly my case - i want to changed identity type.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "convert" an existing column into an IDENTITY column - you have to create a new column as INT IDENTITY:

```
ALTER TABLE MCheckTypes 
ADD NewID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: So annoying, so I need to drop existing column and recreate a new one? Why SQL have this kind of restriction?

Comment: @Bryan No. you can keep current one. once you create newid column you can drop old column and rename the newID as ID. but all your references will be lost which is based on old id.

Comment: But I want the same field name so I don't need to adjust my application code. Is it possible to have the same field name on 1 table?

Comment: @Bryan no. you can't have two column with same name.

Comment: yes that's it. create new column, drop old, rename the new column.

Comment: @Bryan but beware, If your current ID has reference in another tables. You can't drop column or your references will be mismatched.

Comment: yeah,thank you. but I can't see why MSSQL create this kind of restriction that doesn't allow existing column to be an IDENTITY type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65338/discussion-between-dh-and-bryan).